# How to implement Slide-out menu for iOS Apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I just wanted to implement slide-out menu like implemented in this snapshot below:

[image]

Could anybody guide me how to go for it.

Thanks
V@run

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but I'm guessing those who did might be objecting to your wanting to use a slide out menu. These are discouraged by Apple as not user-friendly and not iOS standard. They would rather you use a tab bar menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESideMenu is a great library that I've used more than once. You can find it on Github here: https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Patrick's link will give you most of what you want. If you really want the 3D look where the menu appears to be tilted away you'll have to learn how to use Core Animation with transformation matrixes that create perspective. Do a search on "Adding Perspective to Your Animations" in the Xcode help system for info on how to get perspective.

In short, it involves setting the M34 field of a CATransform3D to a small negative value after rotating the layer around the desired axis. (In this case you'd want to rotate around the y axis.)